# base64 image is null on the POST payload - Angular

Tags: angular, post, base64

I am trying to send an image to the backend, after it is converted to `base64`, but on the POST payload the image seems to be `null`.

```
user.photo = btoa(image);
console.log('user: ', user);    // user.photo is correct
this.userService.updateUser(user).subscribe(data => {   // user.photo is null
    this.currentUser = data;
}
```

I tried also with a smaller image (0,8 kB) and the problem persists, so I believe the issue is not related to the size of the image. Can someone please advise what may be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not due to size of image. Either the base64 conversion at UI end needs some improvements or the API that you are calling is malformed. Please have a look at the below code for verifying API.

```
 public IHttpActionResult updateUser([FromBody] updateUserModel model)
    {
//model object should have a property of type byte[], for example :- 
// public byte[] File { get; set; }

var fileData = model.File;

}
```

At the angular side you should use the data type as  "any" for the property which is binded to base64Byte array. I am sharing my working code here :-

```
export class LogoImage {
Id: number;
File: any;
TempFile: any;
FileSize: number;
FileType: string;
FilePath: string;
```

}
    // call this function on browse button on change

```
onFileChange(fileInput: any) {
    let fileName = fileInput.target.files[0].name;
    let fileSize = fileInput.target.files[0].size;
    var ext = fileName.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();

    var self = this;
    if (fileInput.target.files && fileInput.target.files[0]) {
        var reader: any = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {


            self.file = e.target.result;

      // following code removes the base64 substring and gives only byte array.
         // it removes data:image/png;base64, from begining 
            this.LogoImage.File = self.file.substring(self.file.indexOf(',') + 1);

    //Initiate the JavaScript Image object.
            var image = new Image();

            //Set the Base64 string return from FileReader as source.
            image.src = e.target.result;

            //Validate the File Height and Width.
            image.onload = function (element) {
                let height = image.height;
                let width = image.width;
     // validation for height and width
                return true;
            };
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]);
    }
}

// html

 <div class="btn-fil-upload btn-file btn-info btn-sm">
                                                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select a file to upload</span>
                                                    <input #fileinputControl tabindex="5" class="fileinput" type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" name="..." />
                                                </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your message! But the base64 conversion result should be a string, right? Since the payload doesn't contain the `user.photo` value, I don't think this is related to the backend, because t he image is never sent.

Comment: Hello @decebal , I have updated my answer so that you can have more clear understanding of it.